# jQuery dataTables - adding row does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

A lot of solutions is found but nothing is working for me. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this code?

My table is like

```
 <table id="allPermission" class=" table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Permission No</th>
                    <th>Permission</th>
                    <th>Command</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Permission No</th>
                    <th>Permission</th>
                    <th>Command</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

and my java script code is here

```js
var tbl = $('#allPermission').DataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "retrieve": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "lengthMenu": [
    [5, 10, 25, -1],
    [5, 10, 25, "All"]
  ],
  "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline({
    url: 'rest/showAllPermissions',
    pages: 2 // number of pages to cache
  }),
  "columns": [{
    "data": "permid"
  }, {
    "data": "permissionname"
  }, {
    "data": "DT_RowId",
    "sortable": false,
    "render": function(data, type, full) {
      var result = "";

      result = '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href=/fieldforce/user/editAdmin/' + full.dt_RowId + ' style="width: 58px;"' + '>' + 'Edit' + '</a>' + '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href=/fieldforce/user/deleteAdmin/' + full.dt_RowId + ' style="margin-left: 15px;"' + '>' + 'Delete' + '</a>';
      return result;
    }
  }],
  "deferRender": true,
  "scrollY": "250px"
});

$('#addPerm').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#loadingGif').css({
    "display": "block"
  });
  $('#formBody').css({
    "display": "none"
  });
  // do ajax submition
  $.ajax({
    url: "/fieldforce/administration/rest/addPermission",
    type: "POST",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
      $('#loadingGif').css({
        "display": "none"
      });
      // $('#addPermission').modal('toggle');
      $('#messageBody').html("Success");
      tbl.row.add({
        "permid": '9',
        "permissionname": 'admin',
        "DT_RowId": '8'
      }).draw();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $('#messageBody').html("Server Error");
    }
  });
});
```

I am using jquery version jquery-1.11.1.min and datatable version is //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
TIA

Comment: what is error you got?

Comment: no error display when i debug. But row does not add

Answer (score 3):

According to : https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html site, you should pass array in add method hence

Try this:

```
 var tbl = $('#allPermission').DataTable();
          tbl.row.add(['9','admin','8']).draw();
```

or according to this : https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()

you can try this :

```
var tbl = $('#allPermission').DataTable();
 tbl.rows.add([{
     "permid": '9',
     "permissionname": 'admin',
     "dt_RowId": '8'
 }]).draw();
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried this already. It makes column mismatch error.

Comment: @Amir, Can your show your code for HTML table. How many columns are there in HTML table?

Comment: You can add both objects and arrays.  See the docs -> **https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()** instead of the example.  BTW, the last code snippet in your answer causes error and does not work, since you basically just try to insert an object to the first column.

Comment: davidkonrad @ so what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

see this example

```js
$(function(){

  var tbl = $('#allPermission').DataTable();
  tbl.row.add(['9','admin','8']).draw();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="allPermission">
  <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>permid</th>
                <th>permissionname</th>
                <th>dt_RowId</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues :

1. You should include a `<tbody>` element. Even though it would work adding rows without a `<tbody>`, there are a serious risk of errors when using dataTables with malformed markup.
2. When adding objects as new rows you *must* have specified which data properties that corresponds to which columns through the [**`columns : [ { data : 'property' } ...]`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option.

So initialise your dataTable like this instead :

```
var tbl = $('#allPermission').DataTable({
    columns: [
        { data: "permid" },
        { data: "permissionname" },
        { data: "dt_RowId" }
    ]    
});
```

and your code works. Demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/eco6cgqe/**

Comment: davidkonrad@ thank you for your valuable two information. I edited my question. Could you please see my latest code and tell me what did i wrong with this code?